# How to say "me neither"?

Tags: translation

Is there an equivalent of "Me neither" as a standalone sentence in Japanese? I know you can say the whole sentence (e.g. "I also can't understand"), but what about "Me neither" on its own?

Answer (score 5):

You can just use 「私も」, 「俺も」, 「僕も」 and such. They can mean both "Me, too" and "Me, neither" depending on the previous statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use も in your sentences.

For example.

私もです　 Me, too.

私もできません　I can't do that thing either.

私も分かりません　I also can't understand.